# rdlc expression in Microsoft report?

Tags: reporting-services

I need to fill a column depended on another column  (Transtype and amount column)
I have a trans column containing two values "D" OR "C"
If D I want multiply amount negative.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, your dataset fields name are Trans and Amount.

```
=IIF(Fields!Trans.Value = "D", Fields!Amount.Value *-1, Fields!Amount.Value )
```